# How to get response from aiohttp ClientError?

Tags: aiohttp

Using aiohttp, if you set `raise_for_status=True`, it will raise a ClientError exception.

Is it possible to access the server's response in that ClientError exception?

For instance, a server could return a 4xx error, with a JSON response explaining why, and it would be interesting to access it to manage the error (such as Stripe's API).

```
try:
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        response = await session.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/user', raise_for_status=True)
except aiohttp.ClientError as e:
    print(e.response.content) # ?
```

Is it possible to access the server's response from the exception part?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to set `raise_for_status=False` (although I don't understand why you wouldn't) you can catch the exception and grab the response json like so:

```
try:
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        response = await session.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/user', raise_for_status=True)
except aiohttp.ClientError as e:
    json = await response.json()
    # do something with json
    # maybe you want to raise your own exception
    # if not, just re-raise e
    raise e
```

Comment: This works only if response is present, which could not be the case in the event of a connection failure for instance.